# Static public method accessing private instance variables in Javascript

Tags: javascript, oop, static, closures

I've been reading Diaz's book Pro JavaScript Design Patterns. Great book. I myself am not a pro by any means. My question: can I have a static function that has access to private instance variables? My program has a bunch of devices, and an output of one can be connected to the input of another. This information is stored in the inputs and outputs arrays. Here's my code:

```
var Device = function(newName) {
    var name = newName;
    var inputs  = new Array();
    var outputs = new Array();
    this.getName() {
        return name;
    }
};
Device.connect = function(outputDevice, inputDevice) {
    outputDevice.outputs.push(inputDevice);
    inputDevice.inputs.push(outputDevice);
};

//implementation
var a = new Device('a');
var b = new Device('b');
Device.connect(a, b);
```

This doesn't seem to work because Device.connect doesn't have access to the devices outputs and inputs arrays. Is there a way to get to them without adding privledged methods (like pushToOutputs) to Device that would expose it?

Thanks!
Steve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eugene Morozov is right - you can't access those variables if you create them in the function as you are. My usual approach here is to make them variables of `this`, but name them so it's clear they're meant to be private:

```
var Device = function(newName) {
    this._name = newName;
    this._inputs  = new Array();
    this._outputs = new Array();
    this.getName() {
        return this._name;
    }
};
Device.connect = function(outputDevice, inputDevice) {
    outputDevice._outputs.push(inputDevice);
    inputDevice._inputs.push(outputDevice);
};

//implementation
var a = new Device('a');
var b = new Device('b');
Device.connect(a, b);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're creating a closure, and there's no way to access closure variables from outside except by using a privileged method.

Frankly, I never felt a need for private variables, especially in Javascript code. So I wouldn't bother and make them public, but that's my opinion.